# @types/jquery and ambient modules

Tags: typescript

after reading few times the ts handbook I studied @types/jquery which contains this:

```
... other interface declarations ...
interface JQueryStatic { ... functions declarations ... }
interface JQuery { ... functions declarations ... }
declare module "jquery" {
    export = $;
}
declare var jQuery: JQueryStatic;
declare var $: JQueryStatic;
```

I reason about it as below:

- contains *export = $;* so should be a module
- contains only
  declarations so should be *ambient* (from ts doc: *We call

declarations that don’t define an implementation “ambient”*)

- contains the *declare module* so should be an *ambient module*

So I conclude that @types/jquery is an ambient module.

Is this conclusion correct? If not then why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite. The module `"jquery"` would be classified as an ambient module and the top-level declarations `jQuery` and `$` are ambient as well. So i guess you might say this is an *ambient declaration file*, it is not a module in the sense that the term is commonly used in this context.